# Pyspark ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmlspark'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jar, importerror

My environment: Ubuntu 64 bit, Spark 2.4.5, Jupyter Notebook.

With internet connection that's fine, I don't get any error:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("Churn Scoring LightGBM") \
.master("local[4]") \
.config("spark.jars.packages","com.microsoft.ml.spark:mmlspark_2.11:0.18.1") \
.getOrCreate()

from mmlspark.lightgbm import LightGBMClassifier
```

But without an internet connection I got related jars (This style recommended by [cloudera docs](https://docs.cloudera.com/machine-learning/cloud/spark/topics/ml-example--locating-and-adding-jars-to-spark-2-configuration.html)):

```
import os
mmlspark_jars_dir = os.path.join(os.environ["SPARK_HOME"], "mmlspark_jars")
mmlspark_jars = [os.path.join(mmlspark_jars_dir, x) for x in os.listdir(mmlspark_jars_dir)]
print(mmlspark_jars)
['/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/com.jcraft_jsch-0.1.54.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/com.microsoft.ml.spark_mmlspark_2.11-0.18.1.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/commons-codec_commons-codec-1.10.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/org.scalatest_scalatest_2.11-3.0.5.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/org.apache.httpcomponents_httpcore-4.4.10.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/org.openpnp_opencv-3.2.0-1.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/commons-logging_commons-logging-1.2.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/com.github.vowpalwabbit_vw-jni-8.7.0.2.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/org.apache.httpcomponents_httpclient-4.5.6.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/org.scala-lang_scala-reflect-2.11.12.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/org.scala-lang.modules_scala-xml_2.11-1.0.6.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/com.microsoft.cntk_cntk-2.4.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/io.spray_spray-json_2.11-1.3.2.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/org.scalactic_scalactic_2.11-3.0.5.jar',
 '/home/erkan/spark/mmlspark_jars/com.microsoft.ml.lightgbm_lightgbmlib-2.2.350.jar']
```

And I had to modify SparkSession like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("Churn Scoring LightGBM") \
.master("local[4]") \
.config("spark.jars", ",".join(mmlspark_jars)) \
.getOrCreate()
```

I observed from terminal and everything seemed fine SparkSession was created. Then I checked Spark UI

[image: SparkUI user added jars]

Then I tried to import:

```
from mmlspark.lightgbm import LightGBMClassifier
```

And got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-df498625321c> in <module>
----> 1 from mmlspark.lightgbm import LightGBMClassifier

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mmlspark'
```

I don't understand that although I see the same jars on SparkUI import doesn't work with the second method.

Comment: So, `",".join(mmlspark_jars)` would work locally, but will fail when you run your code on an actual cluster.

Comment: Thank you  @OneCricketeer, for now, I try local mode.